# Display a string and variable on a label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I realize this is a very basic question, and it's probably been answered before, but I couldn't seem to find the answer.

Basically I want to display some text and then an in integer on a label.  I tried

```
countdownLabel.text = @"%d days left until the end of the semester!" daysBetween;
```

but it didn't work.  I thought maybe I needed to use something like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", daysLeftBetween];
```

but I just can't figure out how to put everything together.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all the bits - just 'string' them together :)

```
countdownLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days left until the end of the semester!", daysBetween];
```

The first parameter to `stringWithFormat` is the format - it can be a combination of literal text and placeholders prefixed with '%'.  The remaining parameters get substituted into the placeholders in left-to-right order.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)